Postman unable access post api in Spring boot ( permitAll() not working in spring-security)
I am trying to post data using postman to spring-boot server , but spring security is not allowing the permited path \api\register . I am beginner , so pls correct me. I have tried other stackoverflow but they are outdated.
Spring Security configuration class
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurity {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        return http.csrf(customizer -> customizer.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests((request )-> request
                        .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/register").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                ).httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                //.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .build();
    }
}

Logs:
024-12-29T10:22:40.456+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/register
2024-12-29T10:22:40.459+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Failed to decode basic authentication token
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationConverter.decode(BasicAuthenticationConverter.java:108) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationConverter.convert(BasicAuthenticationConverter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationConverter.convert(BasicAuthenticationConverter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerMappingIntrospector.lambda$createCacheFilter$3(HandlerMappingIntrospector.java:243) ~[spring-webmvc-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:113) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:74) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebMvcSecurityConfiguration$CompositeFilterChainProxy.doFilter(WebMvcSecurityConfiguration.java:238) ~[spring-security-config-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:362) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:278) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.2.1.jar:6.2.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:164) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:140) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:397) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:905) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.34.jar:10.1.34]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842) ~[na:na]

2024-12-29T10:22:40.462+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2024-12-29T10:22:40.462+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : No match found. Using default entry point org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint@43722ef5
2024-12-29T10:22:40.467+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /error
2024-12-29T10:22:40.469+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured POST /error
2024-12-29T10:22:40.471+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/error", parameters={}
2024-12-29T10:22:40.472+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#error(HttpServletRequest)
2024-12-29T10:22:40.489+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [*/*] and supported [application/json, application/*+json]
2024-12-29T10:22:40.490+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing [{timestamp=Sun Dec 29 10:22:40 IST 2024, status=401, error=Unauthorized, path=/api/register}]
2024-12-29T10:22:40.509+05:30 DEBUG 51443 --- [sample] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 401

Postman
link: http://localhost:8080/api/register
request body:
{
    "id":9,
    "username":"user",
    "password":"122824"
}    

response :
{
    "timestamp": "2024-12-29T04:52:40.479+00:00",
    "status": 401,
    "error": "Unauthorized",
    "path": "/api/register"
}

My code that can duplicate issue : https://github.com/adityadaharwal963/Spring-boot-sample.git
Spring security must allow /api/register path without authorisation
my reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#_real_world_example

i cloned your project and the problem is that you have enabled BASIC authentication, but you have not told spring security where your users credentials are.
To put it simply, you have enabled authentication but no database/datastore so spring thinks your security configuration is incomplete and refuses to load it.
When i cloned your project and ran it, you can see in the logs that this is written:
Using generated security password: 8fa52a7c-8dd8-4791-84b4-a42b4d57202c

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

It straight up tells you that you need to update your security configuration.
Also this means that your security configuration is not run, and the default spring security configuration is run instead. This is clearly documented in the getting started portion of the spring security documentation.
Then if you read in the Username/Password section of the docs it is also clearly stated that if you are to configure custom authentication you need to tell spring security where the users credentials are. This is done by using the UserDetailsService interface.
For instance by defining a InMemoryUserDetailsService.
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    UserDetails userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
        .username("user")
        .password("password")
        .roles("USER")
        .build();

    return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(userDetails);
}

Or by for instance implementing the UserDetailsService interface to fetch user details from maybe a database etc.
I would suggest that you need to start to read the spring security documentation if you plan on implementing security using spring security, otherwise you are going to have a very rough time.
Start out by reading the two architecture chapters that will explain all the building blocks in spring security. All the strange words and interfaces/classes
Architecture
Authentication Architecture
Then go on to reading how username/password authentication works
Also lastly, i could only come to this conclusion if i ran your application locally.
This question would of been impossible to answer without having access to the full logs. That's why its so important that you always provide the full logs, when asking for help, and even better the source code with a minimal running example.

Thanks for reply, I read the documentation and understand the default spring security configuration is run, I updated my code and it's running properly. Thanks!!
